# How to create signed transactions like OpenSea

Tags: ethereum, opensea

There is an awesome feature on the OpenSea market, where you can leave an offer to buy an item by signing a transaction. But on-chain it will be approved only when the seller selects 1 of the offers, and then accepts it, by paying for the broadcast.

I could not find a detailed explanation of how this code works on OpenSea. Can you share the documentation and explain how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the EIP712 standard
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4